# How to get AngularJs shopping cart to work as intended

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple shopping AngularJs app. It displays the list of products as intended. You can add a product to the cart and it displays the product name and price in the cart and updates the total price. However, if you add a second product, it doesn't display the second product's name. It just adds the previously added product's price to the total instead of the new product price. So it doesn't ng-repeat the products you push into $scope.cart.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-8" ng-repeat="category in categories">
     <h2>{{category.categoryName}}</h2>
     <div ng-repeat="product in category.products track by $index">
       <div class="panel">
         <img ng-src="{{product.image}}">
         <h6>{{product.name}}</h6>
         <p>{{product.price}}</p>
         <button class="btn btn-sm" ng-click="addItemToCart(product)">Add to Cart</button> 
       </div>
     </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
     <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="products in cart">
       <li class="list-group-item">
         {{products.name}} |{{products.count}}| {{products.price*products.count}} 
         <input class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button" ng-click="removeItemCart(products)" value="Remove" />               
       </li>
       <h5>Number of items in cart: {{productsNumber}}</h5>
     </ul>
     <h4>Total: R{{total}}.</h4>
     <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Checkout</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is my AngularJs:

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);

    app.controller('productsCtrl', ['$scope','$cookies', function($scope,$cookies){

        $scope.categories = productsData;
        // Add ids to the array objects //
        $scope.categories.forEach( function(d, i){ d.id = i+1; });
        $scope.cart = [];
        $scope.total = 0;
        $scope.productsNumber = $scope.cart.length;

        if (!angular.isUndefined($cookies.get('cart'))) {
            $scope.cart =  $cookies.getObject('cart');
        }

        $scope.addItemToCart = function(product){

            if ($scope.cart.length === 0){
                product.count = 1;
                $scope.cart.push(product);
            } else {
                var repeat = false;
                for(var i = 0; i< $scope.cart.length; i++){
                    if($scope.cart[i].id === product.id){
                        repeat = true;
                        $scope.cart[i].count +=1;
                    }
                }
                if (!repeat) {
                    product.count = 1;
                    $scope.cart.push(product);  
                }
            }
            var expireDate = new Date();
            expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
            $cookies.putObject('cart', $scope.cart,  {'expires': expireDate});
            $scope.cart = $cookies.getObject('cart');

            $scope.total += parseFloat(product.price);
            $cookies.put('total', $scope.total,  {'expires': expireDate});
        };

        $scope.removeItemCart = function(product){

            if(product.count > 1){
                product.count -= 1;
                var expireDate = new Date();
                expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
                $cookies.putObject('cart', $scope.cart, {'expires': expireDate});
                $scope.cart = $cookies.getObject('cart');
            }
            else if(product.count === 1){
                var index = $scope.cart.indexOf(product);
                $scope.cart.splice(index);
                expireDate = new Date();
                expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
                $cookies.putObject('cart', $scope.cart, {'expires': expireDate});
                $scope.cart = $cookies.getObject('cart');

            }

            $scope.total -= parseFloat(product.price);
            $cookies.put('total', $scope.total,  {'expires': expireDate});

        };

    }]);

    var productsData = [
    {
        categoryName: "Gas Cylinders",
        products: [
        {
            name: "15kg Gas Cylinder",
            image: "images/gas4.jpg",
            price: 50
        },
        {
            name: "DEFY 4 Burner Gas Stove",
            image: "images/stove2.jpg",
            price: 90
        }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        categoryName: "Electronics",
        products: [
        {
            name: "Samsung Galaxy J4 Core",
            image: "images/j4-core.jpg",
            price: 100
        },
        {
            name: "40'' FHD Hisense TV",
            image: "images/tv2.jpg",
            price: 200
        }
        ]
    } 
    ];

})();
```

I have tried to dynamically add product ids to the $scope.cart but it doesn't help.

Comment: The first issue I see is, when you're adding id in this line: $scope.categories.forEach( function(d, i){ d.id = i+1; });    it is adding id at category level not at products array inside it. The productsData is an array of array. The inner array has products that customers will add to cart and it should have IDs. Not at the outer array level.

Comment: Thanks a million, man. It solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I see is, when you're adding id in this line: $scope.categories.forEach( function(d, i){ d.id = i+1; }); it is adding id at category level not at products array inside it. The productsData is an array of array. The inner array has products that customers will add to cart and it should have IDs. Not at the outer array level.

So the logic to assign IDs to products should change. Else the JS code which is based on IDs will fail.